# Playsound throwing error "returned non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: nlp, assistant

I am trying to build a voice assistant. I am facing a problem with the playsound library. Please view my code snippet.

```
def respond(output):
    """
    function to respond to user questions
    """
    num=0
    print(output)
    num += 1
    response=gTTS(text=output, lang='en')
    file = str(num)+".mp3"
    response.save(file)
    play(file, True) #playsound import playsound as play

if __name__=='__main__':
    respond("Hi! I am Zoya, your personal assistant")
```

My audio file is getting generated, however at the line play(file,True) it is throwing the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-be0c0a53e7e6> in <module>()
      1 if __name__=='__main__':
----> 2     respond("Hi! I am Zoya, your personal assistant")
      3 
      4     while(1):
      5         respond("How can I help you?")

6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    361         if cmd is None:
    362             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 363         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    364     return 0
    365 

CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/playsound.py', '1.mp3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How do I resolve the issue?
I would also like to mention that I am working on google colab.

Comment: Try giving a full file path when you save and play the sound file.

Comment: I tried. Still getting the same error.

>>play("/content/1.mp3")

>>CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/playsound.py', '/content/1.mp3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the PyObjC library to bridge the gap between python and objective C gap. Playsound library uses subprocess which are dependent on PyObjC library. When it returns exit status 1 it means that it wasn't able to complete the process because of unavailability of some dependencies.

This is my first answer on stack overflow, please don't mind any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use PyObjC, however, that's only for MacOS. It doesn't necessarily solve the problem for Windows.