# Playsound issue: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-playsound

I have a method that I found online. The purpose of the code is for python to say words. Code for the method is below:

```
def respond(output):
   num=0
   print(output)
   num += 1
   response=gTTS(text=output, lang='en')
   file = str(num)+".mp3"
   response.save(file)
   playsound.playsound(file, True)  # <-- Error here.
   os.remove(file)
```

An error is occurring on the 7th line inside the function - `playsound.playsound(file, True)`. I looked at another StackOverflow post where the person who had basically the same problem: [Playsound throwing error "returned non-zero exit status 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108130/playsound-throwing-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1), and I tried the solution that was recommended on the post. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. I'd like to ask if there is another solution to the problem I have.

Error message is:

```
Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/playsound.py', '1.mp3']'
  returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: The error message doesn't tell you much about what went wrong. I suggest that you try passing a complete (aka absolute) path to the mp3 file — you're currently only passing a relative one and the problem could simply be "file not found".

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will try that.